# Est-ce que le verbe « agender » est vraiment limité à la Suisse?

Tags: régionalismes, vocabulaire, suisse

Je me suis toujours demandé pourquoi les correcteurs d'orthographe n'aiment pas quand « j'agende » des rendez-vous. Après un petit tour de Google, je vois

> Noter un rendez-vous (Suisse)

Je voudrais savoir si ça se dit quand-même ailleurs, mais n'est pas considéré comme 'correct', ou si c'est vraiment une élocution romande.

Answer (score 9):

Réaction du Français qui a seulement lu le titre et qui s'apprête déjà à actionner le bouton « edit » : mais il a voulu écrire « amender » ou « agencer » ?

Pour info, sans le mot « rendez-vous » j'aurais été incapable de comprendre la question…
Il ne me reste plus qu'à <s>noter ça dans</s> cahietter l'usage de ce mot étrange.

Answer (score 8):

Je (français) ne connais pas ce mot, et je ne l'aurais pas forcément compris dans le sens que tu décris : j'aurais plutôt pensé au sens de « décider la date d'un rendez-vous ». Quand je cherche sur [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22agender%22+lang%3Afr), je vois des usages des deux sens, qui m'ont tous l'air de provenir de Suisse (et beaucoup de résultats parasites, ce qui laisse penser que le mot est très peu utilisé) :

> [N'oubliez pas d'agender les trois premières soirées !](http://www.caprices.ch/2011/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=319%3Acaprices-2011-programmation&catid=41%3Aactu&Itemid=218&lang=fr)
>   [Ces partis ne jugent même pas nécessaire d'agender une séance spéciale [...].](http://www.svp.ch/g3.cms/s_page/83150/CACHE/true/NEWS_NEWSCONTRACTOR_DISPLAY_TYPE/detail/NEWS_NEWSCONTRACTOR_YEAR/2005/NEWS_ID/652/STREAMING/false/S_NAME/communiquesmobile/lang/FR)

[Il semblerait](http://www.proz.com/forum/french/204451-agender_un_mot_nouveau_dans_le_dictionnaire.html) que ce mot d'origine suisse fasse son entrée dans le *Petit Robert* 2011/2012, dans le sens de « fixer une date ». Pour l'instant, même [le Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/agender) ne connaît pas.

Answer (score 7):

Jamais entendu en Belgique non plus. Pour décider de la date d'un rendez-vous, on le *planifie* ; pour le noter dans son agenda, on le… note dans son agenda.

Edit:

*Agender* [va être dans Le Petit Robert 2014](http://www.dhnet.be/infos/societe/article/435496/ce-keke-clashe-des-bombasses-cheloues-pour-une-histoire-d-henaurmes-fricadelles.html) - pas encore le TLF mais je suppose que c'est un pas en avant...

Comment: Je confirme. C'est inconnu dans notre partie du monde...

Comment: Perso je "bloque la date". Mais je pourrais vite me faire à "agender", c'est clair et concis...

Answer (score 5):

Je suis Québécoise et je n'avais jamais entendu ce mot auparavant. Il n'apparaît pas dans la plupart de mes ressources (sauf dans le dictionnaire du programme Antidote, où il apparaît avec la mention « Suisse »). Cependant, j'avais compris ce qu'il voulait dire.

Comment: Oh, encore des louanges à porter à Antidote…

Answer (score 2):

C'est effectivement un mot suisse romand. Si ça vous intéresse, il y a un site www.topio.ch qui fait la liste de quantité de mots de patois romands (Vu que la Suisse a 4 langues officielles).... Personnellement, je trouve que nous avons un certain nombre de mots plus parlant et imagés qu'en français. Et j'ai pu remarquer que certains font partie du patois de l'Ardèche...

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que le régionalisme est très localisé.

Autant je ne suis pas surpris qu'une administration me demande «s'il est possible qu'on s'agende parmi», surtout à Lausanne ou à Berne, autant il me semble difficile d'agender une copine, surtout à Genève ou dans le Valais.

Le mot me semble être un import direct du français dit «[fédéral](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_f%C3%A9d%C3%A9ral)», chez nous. Comme quoi, les suisses allemand seraient parfois capable d'inventer des tournures de phrases immédiatement compréhensibles.

Comment: "En Valais", pas "dans le Valais" ! ;)

Comment: Ca dépend du canton du locuteur.