# Existe-t-il des mots trop rares pour être dans le dictionnaire? / Are some words too rare to be in dictionaries?

Tags: usage, lexique, dictionnaires

Par définition, un mot en bon français est dans le dictionnaire, je crois. Mais existe-t-il des mots vraiment français qui n'y sont pas ?

Soit le mot **intranquille**.

Connaissez-vous ce mot ? Il n'est ni dans le TLFI, ni sur le Wiktionnaire, ni dans... mon correcteur orthographique. Mais moi, je le connais. (Impossible de vous dire d'où il me vient.)

Et [une recherche dans Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=FR&q=intranquille) me renvoie 27 résultats, ce qui est certes peu, mais ils sont tous dans des bouquins qui ont l'air très corrects. Et ce n'est même pas un mot nouveau, puisqu'on le trouve déjà au 19ème siècle (enfin... Gallica le trouve...).

Et je n'ai pas l'impression que ce soit du jargon. Sa signification est facile à comprendre, puisqu'il est formé avec *in* et *tranquille*, sur la même idée que incontrôlable, invraisemblable, etc. — des mots qui sont dans les dictionnaires.

Mais si je dis **impaisible**... j'ai l'impression que ce n'est pas français. Ça sonne mal. [Mais Gallica renvoie 4 résultats](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=FR&q=impaisible) tout de même.

Alors comment faire ? L'idée de mots français corrects mais employés trop rarement pour qu'ils soient dans les dictionnaires est-elle juste ? À quoi se fier si oui ?

---

Les réponses m'ont permis d'y voir plus clair, merci.

#### Ce qui me plaît dans les réponses

- La simple réponse **oui** : il existe des mots français corrects qui ne sont pas dans le dictionnaire. (c'est peut être étrange, mais je n'en étais pas sûr)
- L'idée de générer des mots dans une langue.
- Les catégories de mots hors dictionnaire : les néologismes (mots nouveaux), les mots techniques, les mots anciens, les régionalismes.

#### Et moins

- Finalement le problème des mots d'usage faible sur une longue période (tel intranquille, qui n'est ni un mot technique, ni un néologisme, mais reste tout de même employé) n'a pas été décrit. Comme ces termes sont rarement employés, mais employés quand même, cela serait une raison de plus de les mettre dans le dictionnaire, de mon opinion. Peut être faudrait-il que je pose une question spécifique là dessus, maintenant que je suis sûr qu'il existe des mots qui ne sont pas dans le dictionnaire :-)
- L'usage qui expliquerait... l'usage dit comment une langue se parle, mais n'est jamais une explication du pourquoi, de mon opinion.

---

### English summary

Are there French words that are not found in dictionaries? For example, I can't find ***intranquille*** anywhere, yet I know this word, and I can find it in [a few books](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=FR&q=intranquille). On the other hand, I don't think ***impaisible*** is French, yet [Gallica has four hits](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=FR&q=impaisible). So are there French words that are too rare to be in dictionaries?

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par "correct"? Autorisé par Dieu?

Comment: Tout d'abord, il faut reconnaître qu'il n'existe pas "LE" dictionnaire. Il existe des centaines voire des milliers de dictionnaires, tous rédigés par des rédacteurs humains conformément à ses critères de sélection particuliers.

Comment: @Neil Coffey : Oui, correct = autorisé par Dieu.

Comment: @Neil Coffey (deuxième) : oui, je sais... d'où ma question, c'est ce que je voudrais comprendre : si je prends le mot _tavapoukaclupi_... comment vais-je faire pour savoir si c'est du français autorisé par Dieu ?

Comment: Il en existe. Je tombe régulièrement sur des mots que je mets une heure à trouver dans les dicos...

Comment: @Istao J'aime assez *tavapoukaclupi*. Notamment pour désigner des entismades malomprées.

Comment: Les dictionnaires regorgent de mots rares que les locuteurs du français ne connaissent pas, c'est même l'usage premier du dictionnaire : permettre l'accès à des textes qui contiennent des mots que l'on ne connait pas. Pour ce qui est des mots courants de la langue **récents**, ils mettent un bon moment à y apparaître dans la mesure où leur présence n'est pas directement nécessaire puisque que tout le monde les connait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(English version below)*

#### De la productivité

[Là](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1333/1514), la question se pose déjà, et [c'est permis, même sans être dans le dictionnaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1332/1514). Je ne saurais expliquer mieux que [Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4483/1514) le phénomène.

[Je me demande](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/comment-deriver-les-termes-manquants) aussi déjà comment on fait quand on ne sait pas comment dériver. Les réponses ne fusent pas, mais penchent pour la liberté du compositeur.

#### Des mots pas dans le dico

En complément de la réponse de Gilles, tout bon **néologisme** correspond exactement à ce que tu décris : pas (encore ?) un mot du dictionnaire, très peu employé, mais pas forcément par les moindres, pas du bon français pour certains¹, et connus d'un pouillème de la population. D'après [ℝaphink](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/326/1514) :

> Ces nouveaux mots n'entrent dans le dictionnaire qu'une fois qu'ils sont déjà utilisés par une bonne partie de la population[.]

Un autre cas pas mentionné jusqu'à présent est celui des **régionalismes** : [là](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1235/1514), on se plaint que trop peu d'outils les connaissent encore, et *agender* viendrait tout juste de rentrer dans le *Petit Robert*. Entre ceux qui y sont depuis longtemps, et ceux qui n'y seront jamais, toute la gamme existe.

#### À qui se fier ?

Ce sont les locuteurs qui font la langue. Dès lors que tu penses maîtriser ceux qui *sont* dans le dictionnaire, tu peux te fier **à ton propre avis** pour savoir ceux qui sont acceptables sans y être (ils y seront peut-être un jour, si suffisament de gens pensent comme toi).

Revenant à la production, [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1353/1514), on s'amuse avec le préfixe *dé-*, mais on a l'air de conclure que rien n'existe vraiment. Récemment, j'ai proposé [*quoi-faire*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/3294/1514)
et [ça n'a pas plu](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/comment-conjuguer-ce-quon-tient-pour-acquis#comment6579_3294). Pourtant, [certains](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1236/1514) se comprennent très bien. Il faut essayer², et voir ce qui prend.

---

#### On productivity

See [Gilles's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4483), and also https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1333 and https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1332. Words can be “official” even if they aren't found in dictionaries.

[I wonder](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/comment-deriver-les-termes-manquants) how to proceed when we don't know how to make the derivations.

#### On words that aren't in the dictionary

Adding to Gilles's answer, every good **neologism** corresponds to your description exactly: not (yet?) a dictionary word, gets used very rarely but possibly by noteworthy authors, not considered good French by some¹, and known only by a small fraction of the population. Quoting [ℝaphink](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/326):

> These new words are added to dictionaries only when they become used by a large part of the population.

Another case not yet mentioned is **dialectal words**. [Here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1235) is a complaint that too few sources mention them, for example *agender* just made it into the *Petit Robert* (a reference dictionary). There is a whole gamut ranging from words that have been listed forever and words that will never be.

#### Who can I trust?

Language is defined by its speakers. As soon as you think you master the words that are in the dictionary, you can use your own judgement to determine which are acceptable without being recorded in a dictionary (they will eventually be included if enough people agree with you).

Coming back to productivity, [elsewhere](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1353) we have fun with the prefix *dé-* but it seems that the conclusion is that nothing really exists. I recently proposed [*quoi-faire*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/3294/1514)
and [it wasn't appreciated](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/comment-conjuguer-ce-quon-tient-pour-acquis#comment6579_3294). Yet [some](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1236) are just fine. You need to try² and see what sticks.

---

¹ <sub><sup><strike>esprits bornés</strike></sup></sub> pour qui ils « sonnent mal »
² On peut trouver de l'aide quant aux [genre](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/322/1514) et [groupe](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/482/1514), déjà.

Comment: Qui a parlé de néologisme ? Il me semble que la question porte plutôt sur les mots anciens.

Comment: Eh bien… ***je*** parle de néologismes, pour dire qu'ils correspondent à ce dont il parle. Il me semble que la plupart des *archaïsmes* sont encore dans le dictionnaire, eux.

Comment: Eh bien, d'après moi, certains néologismes font partie du bon français avant d'entrer dans le dictionnaire. C'est mon avis et je le partage, aux autres de juger de sa valeur. ❚ Par contre, ça me semble bien répondre à *Existe-t-il des mots trop rares pour être dans le dictionnaire ?*

Comment: Sans jugement de valeur sur la réponse de Nikana Reklawyks (que je n'ai effectivement pas très bien comprite) (mais que je remercie quand même), je précise que, effectivement, ma question porte sur le français dans son ensemble. Ce qui n'empêche nullement de traiter du cas des néologismes, bien sûr. Nikana Reklawyks et Stéphane Gimenez ont donc tous les deux raison. Merci.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Ça devrait être plus orienté dans le sens de la question, maintenant. Je te laisse déterminer la proportion de critiques qui tiennent toujours.

Comment: Je continue de penser que tu réponds à « qu'est-ce que le bon français » qui détourne l'objectif originel de la question (et qui serait fermée avec pour motif *non constructif*). Il faut se rendre à l'évidence qu'ici *bon français* avait pour signification « qui ne soulève pas d'interrogations », soit tout le contraire du néologisme ou du régionalisme.

Answer (score 13):

En fait, le mot est dans le TLF. Mais il y est en deux parties : l'adjectif *[tranquille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tranquille)*, et le préfixe *[in-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/in-)*. Le préfixe *in-* est **[productif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/productif)** (B.1), ce qui signifie que l'on peut librement l'ajouter à des mots auquel il convient syntaxiquement (des adjectifs, aussi des noms et des adverbes). Le sens se déduit mécaniquement des deux parties qui composent le mot. L'article *[in-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/in-)* contient une section « formation et vitalité », qui explique dans quelles circonstances le préfixe peut être utilisé : le préfixe *in-* est « l'un des plus productifs au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle ».

De manière générale, aucun dictionnaire ne peut être complet. La notion de mot n'est pas binaire : il n'y a pas que des mots qui sont clairement des mots français et des mots qui ne sont clairement pas des mots français. Il y a aussi de nombreux mots qui sont à la limite, notamment du jargon technique (par exemple, des composés chimiques) et des compositions productives (en français, ce sont des préfixes et des suffixes). Ces mots limites ont un sens transparent (au moins pour le public auxquels ils sont destinés, dans le cas de jargon technique). On peut dire qu'ils existent potentiellement depuis toujours, mais empiriquement seulement à partir de la première utilisation observée. Les dictionnaires reprennent plus ou moins de ces mots ; dans la mesure où leur sens est transparent, et leur étymologie et prononciation se retrouve sous une autre entrée, s'il n'y a pas de remarque d'usage à faire, une entrée de dictionnaire n'est pas utile.

---

In fact, the word is found in dictionaries, for example in the *Trésor de la langue française. But it's in two parts: the adjective *[tranquille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tranquille)*, and the prefix *[in-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/in-)*. The prefix *in-* is ***productive***, which means that it can be added to words which are syntactically appropriate (adjectives, also nouns and adverbs). The meaning of the compound results mechanically from the meaning of parts. The article about *[in-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/in-)* includes a section “*formation et vitalité*” which explains in what circumstances the prefix can be used and states that *in-* is one of the most productive prefixes in the 20th century.

Generally speaking, no dictionary can be complete. A word is not a yes/no concept: there are words that are clearly French, and words that are clearly not French, but also words that are in gray areas, such as technical jargon (e.g. chemical compounds) and productive combinations (in French, these are prefixes and suffixes). These gray area words have a transparent meaning (at least for their intended audience, in the case of technical jargon). You could say that they have always existed *in potentia*, as Platonic ideals, but they only popped into empirical existence the first time their use was observed. Dictionaries vary regarding their inclusion. Since their meaning is transparent, and their etymology and pronunciation is already given in the entries for the parts, a dictionary entry is not required.

Comment: Ouaip, j'ai tout de suite pensé à 2-méthylbutan-3-ol en lisant la question.

Comment: Je trouve très bonne cette idée de productif. (elle est presque évidente, mais merci de l'avoir dite). Existe-t-il une liste de ces termes productifs ? Le vocabulaire technique n'est pas une excuse : on y trouve une quantité industrielle de termes complètement abscons ; justement, la question que je pose est quasi vitale ici ; que ce soit en pharmacie, en alimentaire, en informatique, les termes sans aucune valeur sémantique fleurissent ; l'usage de l'anglais y est presque un moindre mal. Donc, justement, il me parait très important de soumettre ces mots hors dictionnaire à l'examen critique.

Comment: @Istao Un bon ouvrage sur la langue devrait avoir une liste. Je n'en ai pas trouvé sur Wikipédia. Il est impossible d'avoir une liste exhaustive puisque la productivité, comme le caractère d'être « un mot français », porte une part d'appréciation. Pour ce qui est des domaines techniques, il est normal que des nouveaux mots apparaissent lorsque des nouveaux concepts apparaissent. Ces mots nouveaux ont une valeur sémantique, justement ! (Je ne compte pas la publicité là-dedans.) L'examen critique ne peut venir que lorsque ces mots sortent d'une sphère très restreinte d'innnovateurs.

Comment: @Gilles. Voici la composition d'un produit de parapharmacie, le [Mustela](http://www.e-parapharmacie.fr/mustela-dermo-nettoyant-savon-lot-2--p1759.htm) : aqua, PEG-40, glyceril cocoate, disodium cocoamphodiacetate, sodium coceth sulfate, PEG-7 glyceryl cocoate, PEG-150 distearate, etc. Y a-t-il une micro chance que cette composition ait la moindre valeur sémantique, concrète et réelle ?

Comment: @Istao Bien sûr ! La sémantique est donnée par la [nomenclature internationale des ingrédients cosmétiques](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Nomenclature_of_Cosmetic_Ingredients). Non seulement la sémantique existe, mais elle est bien plus précise que celle de la langue habituelle. Ne confondrais-tu pas sémantique (sens) avec style (forme) ? Les termes techniques ont en général une sémantique bien définie, et un linguiste n'a pas son mot à dire dessus (sauf s'il s'agit d'un terme technique de linguistique bien sûr).

Comment: J'ai upvoté le commentaire mais il faut quand même remarquer que le nom d'un composé (la façon dont il est construit à partir de racines connues) ne suffit en général pas pour déduire ou deviner sa sémantique.

Comment: Merci de cette réponse très utile. J'avais notamment toujours été infoutu de comprendre pourquoi *infoutu* n'était pas dans le dictionnaire.

Comment: Il me semble que le mot « intranquille » manque vraiment dans le TLFi : il ne laisse une trace dans le matériel imprimé que depuis 1980, pas assez pour avoir été pris au sérieux par les responsables du dictionnaire ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intranquille&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintranquille%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cintranquille%3B%2Cc0)).

Answer (score 6):

Oui. Je pense par exemple aux mots qui tombent dans l'oubli. Ces mots sortent du dictionnaire car ils ne sont (presque) plus employés par personne.

Comment: [J'appelle](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/existe-t-il-des-mots-trop-rares-pour-etre-dans-le-dictionnaire#comment8174_4482) ça des archaïsmes, et tu as raison, certains doivent tomber suffisament en désuétude pour *sortir* du dictionnaire. La question se pose peut-être encore plus de savoir s'ils restent du « bon français », une fois que des linguistes l'en ont *intentionellement* exclus, quand même (que par rapport à ce que [je mentionne](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4482/1514), simplement pas très répandu). +1 parce que je les aime quand même.

Comment: `Bernard Pivot` à consacré un livre à ce phénomène: `http://www.albin-michel.fr/100-Mots-a-sauver-EAN=9782226143846`. Les dictionnaires grand public grossissent peut voir pas du tout (contraintes diverses: coté pratique, maintient des coûts de production...) alors que de nouveaux mots y sont ajoutés, donc il faut bien que des mots soient supprimés...

Comment: D'une certaine manière, ceci devrait être la meilleure réponse, car dans un sens l'immense majorité des mots trop rares pour être dans le dictionnaire sont les mots qui n'y sont plus. J'ai un dictionnaire sous la main que j'ai plaisir à consulter assez souvent, qui date de 1922. Le nombre de mots que je n'ai strictement jamais entendu est effarant, d'une part, mais d'autre part il n'est pas rare de trouver des mots dont *aucun des mots de la définition* n'est employé aujourd'hui !. Exemple : **"Affutiau : (n.m.) Brimborion, affiquet."**

Answer (score 3):

Pardon d'avance, mais ceci n'est pas une *vraie* réponse. C'est (me semble-t-il) la réponse de Léo Ferré à ta question...

Extrait de la chanson *Préface* :

> La poésie contemporaine ne chante plus, elle rampe
>   Elle a cependant le privilège de la distinction
>   Elle ne fréquente pas les mots mal famés, elle les ignore
>   On ne prend les mots qu'avec des gants
>   À menstruel, on préfère périodique
>   Et l'on va répétant qu'il est des termes médicaux qui ne doivent pas sortir des laboratoires et du codex
>
> Le snobisme scolaire qui consiste, en poésie, à n'employer que certains mots déterminés, à la priver de certains autres, qu'ils soient techniques, médicaux, populaires ou argotiques, me fait penser au prestige du rince-doigts et du baise-main
>   Ce n'est pas le rince-doigts qui fait les mains propres ni le baise-main qui fait la tendresse
>   Ce n'est pas le mot qui fait la poésie mais la poésie qui illustre le mot

Aucun dictionnaire ne contient tout le langage. Ce n'est qu'un outil ciblé et daté.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a le cas des mots scientifiques ou techniques qui ne sont utilisés que par un groupe de francophones suffisamment restreint pour être les seuls à en avoir besoin.

Je pense particulièrement aux termes barbares comme *Hydroclorohidratocloratyle* et toutes sortes de termes relevant de disciplines très poussées qui ont leur place dans une encyclopédie plus que dans un dictionnaire.