# Comment traduire « migrability » ?

Tags: traduction, néologismes

Je cherche un mot pour exprimer la « qualité de ce qui peut être migré », en anglais « *migrability* ».

D'après le *Larousse*, les mots « migrable » et « migrabilité » n'existent pas en français.

Le mot « migrabilité » est-il suffisamment clair pour être utilisé et compris ?
Sinon, comment traduire ce mot ?

Comment: Voir http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/existe-t-il-des-mots-trop-rares-pour-%C3%AAtre-dans-le-dictionnaire — un mot peut être dans le dictionnaire par morceaux : racine plus suffixe.

Comment: Je ne savais pas, merci pour le lien!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Après une rapide recherche, *migrability* et *migrable* ne semblent pas être attestés non plus en anglais.

Les seuls exemples que je trouve sont des exemples scientifiques ([ici](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fr&q=migrability&btnG=&lr=)). Dans ce cas, si c'est un néologisme scientifique, ça ne me choque pas de créer le néologisme équivalent en français : *migrabilité*. Ce néologisme semble être adapté, et je ne vois pas de meilleure façon de dire ça.

> Migrability of PVC plasticizers <–> Migrabilité des plastifiants du PVC
>
> Migrability: A Diffusion Model of Migration  <-> Migrabilité : un modèle de diffusion pour la migration

---

EDIT :
La [recherche](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=migrabilit%C3%A9&btnG=&lr=) du mot en français dans des publications scientifiques donne quelques exemples d'utilisation de ce néologisme. [Ce document](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41558204) datant de 1984 (malheureusement en accès restreint…) donne

> Migrabilité : ce terme n'est pas attesté dans les ouvrages que nous avons consultés, c'est un néologisme facilement compréhensible.

Answer (score 1):

Rien n'interdit d'employer un anglicisme, un néologisme ou d'inventer une traduction, il faut seulement l'expliquer quelque part dans l'exposé ou dans le document et préciser que c'est déjà un néologisme dans la langue d'origine.

Les mots que vous proposez sont audibles, j'ai bien entendu 'digitalisé' pour numérisé dit par un conférencier qui essayait d'avoir un langage soutenu.
... Il s'était perdu en plein  milieu de la manche nageant le franglais sans grande élégance.

---

***EDIT*** : Essai de traduction

> Potentiel migratoire.

Cela devrait convenir aux sciences et techniques modernes, aux amateurs d’estives et, hélas, à ceux qui souffrent des conflits.

Comment: Dommage. C'est probablement [une des erreurs qui passent le plus mal](https://twitter.com/numeriquebordel) dans les milieux un tant soit peu spécialisés. Mais étant donné le contexte, je pense que l'intervenant pouvait être pardonné.