# Adjectif qui signifie « peut être inspecté »

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un adjectif pour dire « peut être inspecté ». J'ai cherché *inspectable* dans le dictionnaire Larousse, sans résultats.

Comment: _Inspectable_ se dit dans le milieu enseignant, par exemple l'année où un professeur est susceptible de recevoir la visite d'un inspecteur.

Comment: "Inspection(s) possible(s)"

Comment: Pour information, « [_inspectable_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inspectable) » existe en anglais, mais [WordReference n'est pas en mesure de fournir une traduction directe](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/inspectable).

Comment: If the inspection needs to be a bit deeper, maybe you could call it “[sondable](http://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/sondable)” or at least “pas insondable” (since I don’t think the positive version really exists [& please note that the double negative suggestion was a joke!]). On the other end of the spectrum, if only a casual inspection is required maybe you could call it “[observable](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/observable)” (or in the case of “un regard” [another joke alert!]: “[regardable](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/regardable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Inspectable* n'est pas dans les dictionnaires, mais il sera probablement compris par la majorité des gens. Dans un contexte plus formel, il sera préférable d'avoir recours à un synonyme qui variera selon le contexte.

On peut penser à

- Vérifiable
- Contrôlable
- Testable
- Examinable

L'idéal serait d'utiliser une locution plus étoffée pour rendre l'idée, telle que « dont on peut faire l'inspection » ou autre, selon la connotation que l'on veut donner.

Comment: Au niveau logiciel(doit être court et concis), je crois opter pour "Inspection possible"

Answer (score 3):

***Inspectable*** est correct. Ce mot est formé de la racine du verbe *[inspecter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inspecter)* et du suffixe [-able](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-able). Le suffixe -able est **[productif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/productif)** (B.1), ce qui signifie que l'on peut construire des mots qui l'utilisent à partir d'éléments valide (voir aussi
[Existe-t-il des mots trop rares pour être dans le dictionnaire? / Are some words too rare to be in dictionaries?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/existe-t-il-des-mots-trop-rares-pour-%C3%AAtre-dans-le-dictionnaire/4483#4483)). L'[article du *Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-able) discute de sa productivité. Je cite les passages pertinents (en complétant les abréviations) :

> Le suffixe est très productif à toutes les époques du français. […] Les formations récentes sont nombreuses […]. Le suffixe est disponible pour la plupart des verbes transitifs directs. Si tous les adjectifs n'existent pas, il ne semble pas impossible de les former, leur présence dans les nomenclatures de dictionnaires ne se justifiant que lorsque l'adjectif est relativement autonome du verbe.

On le voit bien, le fait qu'un composé ne soit « pas dans le dico » n'empêche pas d'utiliser le mot, en partant du radical d'un verbe, pour signifier « que l'on peut <verbe> ».

Même si le mot est très rare, [on le trouve dans quelques textes du XIX<sup>e</sup>](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inspectable%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks), pour caractériser ce qu'un inspecteur peut inspecter.

Answer (score 2):

J'aurai également dit "inspectable". Je pense que ce n'est pas dans le dictionnaire parce que c'est spécifique au développement web (n'est-ce pas ?), et donc nouveau.
Dans une enquête policière, on n'a aucune raison de dire qu'une affaire est "inspectable"... Alors qu'un formulaire HTML, oui :)

Comment: Dans mon cas, dans un logiciel d'inspection d'infrastructures, on parle d'un élément(un regard, une conduite d'aqueduc) qui peut être inspecté.